# Can't tap on UITextField (iOS 6)

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, ios6

I have an UITextField and UIButton in a .xib. Button is under the field and inactive (user interaction disabled).

User taps on textField, than keyboard appears and user can enter a text...

Problem: some users with iOS6 can not tap on the textField (keyboard not appears), but on the other views everything is working fine (and it was working perfect on iOS5).

I have tested my app on the different devices, but i can't reproduce the error: it is working as it has to.

Maybe somebody has an idea what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not help, but I thought I'd contribute an answer just in case it does help you out.

How are your controllers organised? Are you newing up Nav controllers (or similar) when you could rearrange the structure and simiplify things?

I had a similar problem with my app where a text field worked in iOS4 but not in iOS5. It turned out it was the organisation of my controllers that was causing the problem as it wasn't semantically correct. I had a scene with 2 buttons (a log in and a sign up), each of which spawned a new Nav controller with appropriate scenes on top of that. The fields for entering email/password worked in iOS4 and not in iOS5.

I rearranged things and put the Nav controller first (before the scene with log in and sign up), so this Nav controller was reused, rather then having 2 others getting newed-up and killed as you moved back and forth.  Everything worked a treat.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my iPhone App,

I fixed it by killing the following methods:

`- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

`- (BOOL)isViewLoaded`

For some reason they were making the Keypad unresponsive when you tap your finger on the Textfield.

Answer (score 1):

This may help. We had a similar problem and it was related to storyboards. If you are using storyboards delete the segue that leads to the view controller and then relink the view controller. It doesn't make any sense but that's what fixed our problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was trying to show a UIPicker when a textfield was clicked. So, I had my ViewController conforming to the UITextViewDelegate. Thus, I had the following function:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if (textField == districtTextField) {
        districtPickerView.hidden = false
    }
    return false
}
```

The issue was that I was returning false for all fields, and I need to only return false for the field that controlled the UIPicker. Here is the correct version

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if (textField == districtTextField) {
        districtPickerView.hidden = false
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: This helped. I had a lot of subclassing going on and I had buried an `isReadOnly` flag somewhere that would return `false` here